# How to Repair Persisent Live USB made using mkusb

Tags: usb, persistence, mkusb

I had a working persistent live USB that I made using mkusb and it served me well for several months. It then stopped booting.

I get to the screen where I can select Persistent Live, USB Persistent Live to  RAM, etc. I select Persistent Live (selecting Persistent Live to RAM doesn't help either). It continues but then stays stuck on the screen during the Ubuntu boot where the dots keep cycling. Upon touching the power button, I see a log of lines that show the following errors along with other lines:

> Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS [a few more characters follow but I
>   cannot make it out]
>
> Failed to start Login Service
>
> There is a line each for a Failed to Start for (I am recreating the
>   list from shorthand notes so please don't mind case differences or
>   other slight variations--let me know if you need the exact):
>
> login service
>   VirtualBox Linux kernel module
>   Accounts Service
>   Thermal Daemon Service
>   Network Manager Service
>   Dependency failed for Network Manager Wait Online

During the boot process, if I select the last option to check and do any fixes (versus selecting Persistent Live Boot), it says nothing was broken and asks me to reboot.

From what I can make out from [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent), I need to create a new live usb and transfer the home directory to it. I am having trouble creating a new one (will create a separate thread) but wanted to see if anyone has encountered a similar issue and fixed it without creating a new persistent live usb.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your casper-rw partition full? if so try increasing it's size.

Answer (score 0):

When the check is successful, you should also be able to boot the persistent live drive in live-only mode, 'Try Ubuntu'. (You can try that).

I think the problem is that some system data saved in the casper-rw partition is corrupted. You should **backup your home directory** to another partition or even better to another drive. (Usually the home directory is healthy.)

Then it is probably enough to remove all directories and files from the casper-rw partition, and after that restore the home directory.

You will have to re-install program packages that you had installed, but personal files and settings (stored in your home directory) will survive.

If the file system itself is corrupted in the casper-rw partition you should create a new ext4 partition (and remove journaling if you want to decrease the wear of the memory cells). And then restore the home directory and re-install program packages.

---

But I find it easier to create a fresh persistent live drive and restore the home directory and re-install program packages.